# awk: delete lines where fields 1 and 2 are duplicate

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

Example of file with duplicate lines:

```
 # more  file.csv

 spark2-env,spark_thrift_cmd_opts,--driver-memory 15g --executor-cores 7
 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.memory.offHeap.enabled,true
 mapred-site,yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts,-Xmx5324m -Dhdp.version=${hdp.version}
 spark2-env,spark_thrift_cmd_opts,--driver-memory 15g --executor-cores 7
```

We created the following awk in order to delete the lines with duplicate strings only in fields 1 and 2, but awk from some unclear reason also deletes  the line where field 3 is duplicate.

What is wrong with my awk syntax?

```
 # awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++; next} a[$1,$2]==1'  blueprint_param_file.csv  blueprint_param_file.csv

 spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.memory.offHeap.enabled,true
 mapred-site,yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts,-Xmx5324m -Dhdp.version=\${hdp.version}
```

Expected output:

```
spark2-env,spark_thrift_cmd_opts,--driver-memory 15g --executor-cores 7
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.memory.offHeap.enabled,true
mapred-site,yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts,-Xmx5324m -
```

Comment: You already asked this. In how does your new question differ from the one that was answered?

Comment: no duplicate just we found bug in the previous answer

Comment: How about `sort -t, -suk1,2`

Comment: This is a Q&A site. If there is a bug in previous answer, it needs to get fixed there!

Answer (score 3):

No need to process the same file twice, it's enough to apply the following logic:

```
awk -F, '!a[$1,$2]++' blueprint_param_file.csv
```

- `!a[$1,$2]++` - ensures that a *crucial* key(concatenation of the 1st and 2nd field) occurs only once in array `a`, thereby excluding duplicates

The output:

```
spark2-env,spark_thrift_cmd_opts,--driver-memory 15g --executor-cores 7
spark2-thrift-sparkconf,spark.memory.offHeap.enabled,true
mapred-site,yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts,-Xmx5324m -Dhdp.version=${hdp.version}
```